# How do I get the file to print to the screen?

Tags: c, file

I am trying to get the data from quiz_scores.txt to print to the screen so I can scan it into an array but I don't know how. Do I need to hard-code the file into my program and if so how?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(void)
{
    //initializing variables

    FILE *es;
    FILE *hs;
    int num=0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int cols=10;
    int rows=10;
    int qid, s;
    int quizarray[0][0];
    int MAX_LENGTH=15;
    char *result0;
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];
    FILE *qs="C:\\quiz_scores.txt";

    qs = fopen("quiz_scores.txt", "r");

    /*for (i=0; i<cols; i++){
        for (j=0; j<rows; j++){
            quizarray[i][j]=0;
            fscanf(qs, "%d%d", quizarray[i][j]);
        }
    }
*/ 
    while(fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, qs))
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    if(qs == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /*for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fprintf(qs, "%d\n");
    }
    fclose(qs);*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should format & clean up your question if you expect people to help you.

Comment: I am so lost I can't do that.

Comment: What is file contents?

Comment: student id numbers and quiz scores. so just numbers.

Comment: ".. to print to the screen so I can scan it into an array" -- what does that mean? You already print it to screen, but this has nothing to do with 'scan into an array'. If your target array is `quizarray`, it's a bit small isn't it?

Comment: It doesn't print to the screen though. I need the data in the file quiz_scores to print to the screen.

Comment: There are only 5 scores in the quiz_scores file

Comment: 5 scores per line ? How many students? The number unknown?

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I know what you want to happen, read numbers from the file quiz_scores.txt into your 2d array and print them,correct?. I hope these corrections will allow you to do just that and also that you will understand why it wouldn't work before. The rest of the program is for you to do yourself, good luck!!

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <strings.h>

int main(void)
{
    //initializing variables
    int num=0,i,j,cols=10,rows=10;//just smooshed all onto the same line cause it was annoying me
    int quizarray[10][10];//You declared a 2d array with 0 elements(you wanted one with ten rows and columns I presume 10 teams 10 rounds)
    FILE *qs = fopen("quiz_scores.txt", "r");//Your declaration of the file pointer was incorrect
    if(qs == NULL)//This if needs to go before you read anything from the file otherwise its kind of redundant
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<cols; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<rows; j++)
        {
            quizarray[i][j]=0;
            fscanf(qs,"%d", &quizarray[i][j]);//Them scanfs need &s mate  
            \\and don't try to scan in two integer into one array element
            printf("%d",quizarray[i][j]);
            if(j<rows-1)
                printf("-");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(qs);//Dont comment fclose out bad things will happen :P
    return 0;
}
```